# I cant get text to change on my android application on android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

In my code I have a letter appear in Russian, I then write the sound it is in English. Press a submit button and it checks if I am correct, shows correct or incorrect based on if I was right then shows the next letter. My code will show a new random letter each time I go to the page, however when I press the submit button it doesn't change the text to say weather I was right or not. I used the debug menu to find that it does check if my answer was correct and can detect if it is right, however it doesn't change anything visually

```
package com.example.russianpractice

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.SystemClock.sleep
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class Alphabet : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet)

        val rnd = ((-1..34).random()).toInt();
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.back)
        val buttonA = findViewById<Button>(R.id.answer)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer_letter)
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.random_Letter)
        val rLetter = arrayOf("А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ё", "Ж", "З", "И", "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ы", "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я")
        val aSound = arrayOf("a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "ye", "yo", "zh", "z", "i", "ey", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "oo", "f", "kh", "ts", "ch", "sh", "shch", "hard", "y", "soft", "e", "yu", "ya")
        var num = rnd
        var check = ""
        text.text = rLetter[num]


        buttonA.setOnClickListener(){
            check = answer.text.toString()
            if (check == aSound[num]) {
                text.text= "Correct"
            } else {
                text.text= "Wrong"
            }
            sleep(1000)
            num = rnd
            text.text = rLetter[num]
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a silly and useless comment, but ... What if you use `text.setText (" Corect "), I understand that you are using kotlin, but I'm pretty sure I've done something like that sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display the result `"Correct"` or `"Wrong"` in the `TextView` (`random_Letter`), which you also use to display the random letter. 
To do so you set the `TextView`'s text to the result and then you use `sleep(1000)` which makes the interface freeze for 1 second and then you display in the same `TextView` the **same** random letter as the previous one.

So finally you don't see the result that you want.

What I suggest is use another `TextView` or a `Toast` to display `"Correct"` or `"Wrong"`:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.back)
val buttonA = findViewById<Button>(R.id.answer)
val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer_letter)
val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.random_Letter)
val rLetter = arrayOf("А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ё", "Ж", "З", "И", "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ы", "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я")
val aSound = arrayOf("a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "ye", "yo", "zh", "z", "i", "ey", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "oo", "f", "kh", "ts", "ch", "sh", "shch", "hard", "y", "soft", "e", "yu", "ya")

var num = (0 until rLetter.size).random()
text.text = rLetter[num]

buttonA.setOnClickListener(){
    Toast.makeText(this, if (answer.text.toString() == aSound[num]) "Correct" else "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    num = (0 until rLetter.size).random()
    text.text = rLetter[num]
}
```

I also changed `((-1..34).random()).toInt()` to `(0 until rLetter.size).random()` for the creation of the random integer, because `-1` does not make sense as you want that random integer to be the index of the array and instead of hardcoding the array's size you can use `rLetter.size`.

Also, inside the listener, after you display the result, you must create each time a **new** random number.